# bash files that do like cat

Tags: bash, cat

I have an exercise where I need to do a file named `my_cat.sh`.

It has to work in the same way as the `cat` command.

Ex:

```
∼/C-DEV-110> echo Hello > test
∼/C-DEV-110> bash my_cat.sh test
Hello
```

I tried to search everywhere on the Internet but couldn't find any answers.

Copy your file `my_cat.sh` and modify it so it takes the file to show as its first parameter.

It's the sentences if it as any other way to find an answers.
(I'm new, so it may be really simple).

I tried to simply out a cat in the nano but i doesn't give back anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `cat` command copies it's arguments, or the [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) if none was specified, to the [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)).

Now, if you had to implement it using cat, your script would look like this

```sh
#!/bin/sh
cat "$@"
```

However, that would be trivial. Now, if you had to implement without resorting to external commands, then you can use the shell's internal (built-in) `read` and `echo` commands combined with a [loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs) to do the job. In order to read from a file instead of the standard input you'll need to use [redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections).

It should look similar to this:

```sh
while read x
do
  echo "$x"
done
```

Something like that would be the inner loop, there will be an other loop for iterating over the input files... for that you can either use "$1" and `shift` with a `while` loop, or a `for` loop over `"$@"`.